# USB port confusion

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, mouse

I have 4 USb ports into my computer and all 4 are working.

Now, I am testing them by simply connecting my mouse to it. Anyways, somehow when i connect it to two USB ports on one side of my computer it gets detected and when I connect it to other two ports on the other side of my computer it does not get detected.

But I think all 4 are working because when I connect my iPhone to the ports which are not able to recognize my mouse are able to recognize my phone and infact charges my phone. So I am confused why would it not detect my mouse. One more thing I noticed is that there are differnt symbold besides all the ports:

1. The ones which detect my mouse says SS besides the USB port
2. The ones which do not detct my mouse say Sata/USB and Power/USB besides it.

Are there any differences in different USB ports that we need to be aware of? If so why?

Comment: Sounds like the port could be a eSATA/USB Combo port. Do you know what motherboard you have ?  The SS ports are USB3 ports which work like normal USB ports.

Comment: You use very vague terms like "recognize my mouse" or "recognize my phone". Can you be a lot more specific? For example, when you say it won't recognize your mouse, do you mean that nothing at all happens -- not even the "bee-boop" sound? And when you say it recognizes your phone, do you mean it reports that the phone is connected and permits to be accessed -- or just that it supplies it with power?

Comment: 1. When mouse in connected not "bee-boop" sound and no unrecognized device in the device manager. 2. When phone is connected it recognizes that the phone is there and starts charging my phone